# java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: D:/tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-; in windows 10

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load the data from HDFS to hive using spark, below are the spark conf

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class MigrationdatainoHive1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("Read csv File to DataSet")
          .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0")
          .config("spark.master", "local")
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .getOrCreate();

        spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");


        String files = "D:\\zomato-india-data-set\\Agra\\1-Agrahotels.csv";

         Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")            
                    .option("header", "true")                           
                    .option("multiline", true)                          
                    .option("sep", "|")                                 
                    .option("quote", "\"")                               
                    .option("dateFormat", "M/d/y")                      
                    .option("inferSchema", true)                        
                     .csv(files);


                 df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("hadoop.Sample");
                 df.printSchema();


    }

}
```

where i was add **.enableHiveSupport()** in spark conf then I am facing below error

```
**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: D:/tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-;**
```

and also I have run the command **C:\Hadoop\Hadoop-2.7.1\bin>winutils.exe chmod 777  C:\tmp\hive**  after that also I am facing the same issue.kindly help to resolve  to this.

and also if possible kindly share  any **sample code** for loading from HDFS to hive using spark.

Comment: Can you also share code how are you saving data to hive

Comment: Srinivas, I had shared the code.kindly go through.

Comment: hive you installed hive in your local ?

Comment: Yes I have  already installed the hive and also I able to create the  database,tables in cmd prompt using hive.

Comment: do you have hive-site.xml ? if yes, can you add it to your resource folder & try again ?